# How to wait for a callback before continuing in PHP

Tags: php, api, callback

I'm working on an online payment solution using a bank API.

When the user enter his creditcard number on the bank website (so I don't have to deal with PCI compliance), the API does a callback to one of my page to send the response of the transaction (approved, time, amount, etc.) and then calls my "return URL" to bring the customer back to my website, but without any information beside a confirmation number.

I have some information to display on the "return URL" that are transmitted to the callback by the API. Therefore, I decided to stock the callback's data in my database to retrieve it later on the "return URL"

How can I be sure on my "return URL" that the callback finished performing its action and that I can start retrieving data from the database ?

Comment: Do you have reasons to suspect that the bank might redirect to your site before it's finished the transaction?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario : Since I'm doing some database work on the callback, I don't want to take the risk to arrive on my site before everything is done. A lag on my server could cause problems I think.

Comment: You cannot be sure unless you check the data. =/ So just make a "done" field in the db and make sure the last action on your callback is updating this field. When checking its value on your returnpage you can decide if the process finished or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say without knowing the API but surely you must be able to check the confirmation number with the banks API to check it is a 'real' confirmation number.

Do this check on your "return URL" and then match the received info with that which is stored in your database on the initial call back. If the information does not match or is not in your database throw a 'waiting/processing' .gif up and retry every 10 secs say until you receive a result else handle a timeout.

Comment: Alright, that's what I was doing so far, was wondering if a "cleaner" solution existed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But sometimes this can take hours for credit cards and days for paypal.

Answer (score 0):

normaly you always display a succes to customer on reutrn url but dont provide any downloads. 
The information abaout the product downloads or confirm emails will be triggered from the callback url.

Because it is still nor possible to wait for the api callback you only able to fwait for the callback and process then the order.